# SQL Select fails when run from sp_prepexec

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Scenario:
SQL 2005
Table VR_MQLOAD with 2 columns - MQKEY (PK, int, not null) and MQDATA (varchar(8000),null)

There is a trigger oninsert of this table, and this trigger calls a stored procedure.

From a query window, I run:

```
declare @P0 as nvarchar(4000)
set @P0 = N'TRIG1420441662MF1991782 CAROLYN 201310021356449320131002Y'
insert into dbo.VR_MQLOAD (MQDATA) values(@P0)
```

The trigger runs, which calls the sp, and everything works fine.

Here's the issue....
We have a external program that is failing.  In profiler, I can see this command being run:

declare @p1 int
set @p1=17
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P0 nvarchar(4000)',N'insert into dbo.VR_MQLOAD (MQDATA) values(@P0)        ',N'TRIG1420473882MF1993755 CAROLYN 201310031519469020131002Y'
select @p1

To me, this looks the exact same.  However, when this executes, the trigger runs, which calls the sp, and the SP fails.  See the SP below....

```
USE [VEHICLE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[VR_UpdateTrigLog]    Script Date: 10/04/2013 11:22:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VR_UpdateTrigLog]
              @sMQData varchar(53),
              @sErrorMsg varchar(255)  OUTPUT
    AS
--
    DECLARE @currentDate datetime
    DECLARE @iCount as integer
--
    DECLARE @sPVI varchar(9)
    DECLARE @sCSN varchar(11)   
    DECLARE @sInputAddress varchar(8)                                
    DECLARE @sTrigDate varchar(8)
    DECLARE @sTrigTime varchar(6)
    DECLARE @sProdDate varchar(8)
    DECLARE @sEventNum varchar(6)
    DECLARE @tmp_TrigDate varchar(9)
    DECLARE @tmp_TrigTime varchar(8)
    DECLARE @tmp_ProdDate varchar(8)
    DECLARE @tmp_CSN varchar(11)
    DECLARE @sUpdateVBI varchar(1)
--
    SELECT @currentDate = GETDATE()
--
    SELECT @sPVI = substring(@sMQData,1,9)
    SELECT @sCSN = substring(@sMQData,10,11)
    SELECT @sInputAddress = substring(@sMQData,21,8)
    SELECT @sTrigDate = substring(@sMQData,29,8)
    SELECT @sTrigTime = substring(@sMQData,37,6)
    SELECT @sEventNum = substring(@sMQData,43,2)
    SELECT @sProdDate = substring(@sMQData,45,8)
    SELECT @sUpdateVBI = substring(@sMQData,53,1)
--
--  Check if rows PVI exists in VBI. 
--  If PVI does not exist, send error message to client, roll back tran
--

    SELECT * 
    FROM vehicle.dbo.vr_VBI
    WHERE pvi=@sPVI
```

If I put a "GoTo Finalize" just before the select statement above, the initial insert into the table will complete and not be rolled back.  If not, then it fails on this select and rolls everything back.

So... what is different about the way this external program does the insert via sp_prepexec versus running it manually via a query window???

Any suggestions on how to see error messges related to WHY it's failing here?  I'm green in troubleshooting in SQL code... not sure how to see the error on this code when it's run from the external program.
BTW... the error that is returned in the logs of the external program is "db_write action is completed with business ERROR: 0 A result set was generated for update."

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does Profiler think that the statement is failing?  If so what error does it capture for it?

Comment: Profiler doesn't seem to give any error messages.

Comment: You do have to configure the Profiler trace to capture Error events and the success/status columns of the command completion events.  If you have done this correctly and you still do not see any errors for that statement, then its probably not failing in SQL Server, and must be a problem with the client code's handling.

Comment: Thanks Barry... I know what you're saying... I've checked all events in profiler for TSql and SPs, etc., so believe I should be seeing an error in SQL if it was there.  I'm leaning toward the client code... will follow up with them on Monday... thx!

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid actions from triggers that return results.

From [Create Trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

**General Trigger Considerations**

*Returning Results*

The ability to return results from triggers will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Triggers that return result sets may cause unexpected behavior in applications that are not designed to work with them. Avoid returning result sets from triggers in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently do this. To prevent triggers from returning result sets, set the disallow results from triggers option to 1.

Comment: Thanks for replies.  Interestingly, I tried running the EXACT code that was in profiler, with just the handle changed to zero, and it works fine when done in a query window.  So now I'm wondering if what is being returned to the external program is not what's expected, and so the external program is rolling back the transaction.  Is it possible that the very first 'select' in the stored procedure will be returning it's return code to the trigger, and in turn back to the app?

Answer (score 0):

FYI... it turns out that the stored procedure was returning what it got from the 'SELECT' statement back to the Trigger, and in turn back to the calling application.  What we did to fix it was to create a parameter and return the results from the SELECT into the parameter, then handle it accordingly.  By returning the results to the parameter it prevented it from being returned back up to the calling application.